# Iterate thru list and check if number is higher or lower, then append a different number to another list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

not sure where I'm doing it wrong but I would like to iterate dataframe column and check if this number is higher or lower than X number and based on that X number append a specific number

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('numbers.csv')
lst = []
for a in df['1']:
    if 51.27>=a>=50:
        lst.append(0)
    elif 52.54>=a>51.27:
        lst.append(-0.5)
    elif 53.81>=a>52.54:
        lst.append(1)
    elif 55.08>=a>53.81:
        lst.append(-1.5)
    elif 56.35>=a>55.08:
        lst.append(-2)
    elif 57.62>=a>56.35:
        lst.append(-2.5)
    elif 58.89>=a>57.62:
        lst.append(-3)
    elif 60.16>=a>58.89:
        lst.append(-3.5)
    elif 61.43>=a>60.16:
        lst.append(-4)
    elif 62.7>=a>61.43:
        lst.append(-4.5)
    elif 63.97>=a>62.7:
        lst.append(-5)
    elif 65.24>=a>63.97:
        lst.append(-5.5)
    elif 66.51>=a>65.24:
        lst.append(-6)
    elif 67.78>=a>66.51:
        lst.append(-6.5)
    elif 69.05>=a>67.78:
        lst.append(-7)
    elif 70.32>=a>69.05:
        lst.append(-7.5)
    elif 71.59>=a>70.32:
        lst.append(-8)
    elif 72.86>=a>71.59:
        lst.append(-8.5)
    elif 74.13>=a>72.86:
        lst.append(-9)
    elif 75.4>=a>74.13:
        lst.append(-9.5)
    elif 76.67>=a>75.4:
        lst.append(-10)
    elif 77.94>=a>76.67:
        lst.append(-10.5)
    elif 79.21>=a>77.94:
        lst.append(-11)
    elif 80.48>=a>79.21:
        lst.append(-11.5)
    elif 81.75>=a>80.48:
        lst.append(-12)
    elif 83.02>=a>81.75:
        lst.append(-12.5)
    elif 84.29>=a>83.02:
        lst.append(-13)
    elif 85.56>=a>84.29:
        lst.append(-13.5)
    elif 86.83>=a>85.56:
        lst.append(-14)
    elif 88.1>=a>86.83:
        lst.append(-14.5)
    elif 89.37>=a>88.1:
        lst.append(-15)
    elif 90.64>=a>89.37:
        lst.append(-15.5)
    elif 91.91>=a>90.64:
        lst.append(-16)
    elif 93.18>=a>91.91:
        lst.append(-16.5)
    elif 94.45>=a>93.18:
        lst.append(-17)
    elif 95.72>=a>94.45:
        lst.append(-17.5)
    elif 96.99>=a>95.72:
        lst.append(-18)
    elif 98.26>=a>96.99:
        lst.append(-18.5)
    elif 99.53>=a>98.26:
        lst.append(-19)
    ######
    elif 50 >= a >= 48.73:
        lst.append(0)
    elif 48.73 > a >= 47.46:
        lst.append(0.5)
    elif 47.46 > a >= 46.19:
        lst.append(1)
    elif 46.19 > a >= 44.92:
        lst.append(1.5)
    elif 44.92 > a >= 43.65:
        lst.append(2)
    elif 43.65 > a >= 42.38:
        lst.append(2.5)
    elif 42.38 > a >= 41.11:
        lst.append(3)
    elif 41.11 > a >= 39.84:
        lst.append(3.5)
    elif 39.84 > a >= 38.57:
        lst.append(4)
    elif 38.57 > a >= 37.3:
        lst.append(4.5)
    elif 37.3 > a >= 36.03:
        lst.append(5)
    elif 36.03 > a >= 34.76:
        lst.append(5.5)
    elif 34.76 > a >= 33.49:
        lst.append(6)
    elif 33.49 > a >= 32.22:
        lst.append(6.5)
    elif 32.22 > a >= 30.95:
        lst.append(7)
    elif 30.95 > a >= 29.68:
        lst.append(7.5)
    elif 29.68 > a >= 28.41:
        lst.append(8)
    elif 28.41 > a >= 27.14:
        lst.append(8.5)
    elif 27.14 > a >= 25.87:
        lst.append(9)
    elif 25.87 > a >= 24.6:
        lst.append(9.5)
    elif 24.6 > a >= 23.33:
        lst.append(10)
    elif 23.33 > a >= 22.06:
        lst.append(10.5)
    elif 22.06> a >= 20.79:
        lst.append(11)
    elif 20.79 > a >= 19.52:
        lst.append(11.5)
    elif 19.52 > a >= 18.25:
        lst.append(12)
    elif 18.25 > a >= 16.98:
        lst.append(12.5)
    elif 16.98 > a >= 15.71:
        lst.append(13)
    elif 15.71 > a >= 14.44:
        lst.append(13.5)
    elif 14.44 > a >= 13.17:
        lst.append(14)
    elif 13.17 > a >= 11.9:
        lst.append(14.5)
    elif 11.9 > a >= 10.63:
        lst.append(15)
    elif 10.63 > a >= 9.36:
        lst.append(15.5)
    elif 9.36 > a >= 8.09:
        lst.append(16)
    elif 8.09 > a >= 6.82:
        lst.append(16.5)
    elif 6.82 > a >= 5.55:
        lst.append(17)
    elif 5.55 > a >= 4.28:
        lst.append(17.5)
    elif 4.28 > a >= 3.01:
        lst.append(18)
    elif 3.01 > a >= 1.74:
        lst.append(18.5)
    elif 1.74 > a >= 0.47:
        lst.append(19)

print(lst)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df3.to_csv("numbers2.csv")
```

So based on what number is iterated as a, specific number should be appended to lst list.
My result is that I get just 19 in every row, so the last number in all these elif clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things to create a more simple implementation:

- make the `elif` checks easier.
- use pandas `apply()`.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_value(a)
    if a>50 and a<51.27  # was 51.27>=a>=50
        return 0
    elif a < 52.54       # was 52.54>=a>51.27
        return -0.5)
    elif a < 53.81       # was 53.81>=a>52.54
        return 1
    elif a < 55.08       # was 55.08>=a>53.81
        lst.append(-1.5)
    # And so on

df = pd.read_csv('numbers.csv')
df['1_new'] = df['1'].apply(get_value)
```

Your new values are now stored with the original values in `df`.

Save only the new values:

```
df['1_new'].to_csv('numbers2.csv')
```

I've not tested the solution but it should give you some inspiration :)

Comment: yes, thanks for make it a bit better. It was actually a mistake on my end with numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to help as you don't tell what numbers you have in the numbers.csv. To solve the problem by yourself, you could 1) check the datatypes of the df: df.dtypes, and 2) add print(a) as the first statement in the for-loop.